# Indexoutofbound Exception invalid index size is

Tags: android, arrays

I am getting error in this line..cant figure why?

```
 private void method() {
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){ 
       DbHelper.add(list.get(i),desc.get(i));
    }
```

Thank you....

Comment: how big is desc?  Perhaps it is smaller than your list.size()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `desc.size()` is less than `list.size()`.

Three options:

- Validate this first:

  ```
  // Using Guava or something similar
  Preconditions.checkState(list.size() == desc.size());
  ```
- Only go as far as the minimum:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size() && i < desc.size(); i++)
  ```
- Combine both `list` and `desc` into *one* list of a composite type. When you have two collections which you iterate over together, quite often that's a sign that you'd be better off with a single collection capturing the combined entity. It depends on the situation, admittedly.